# how to start the wifi AP settings intent in android 4.0?

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My android 4.0 emulation device seems doesn't have a wifi ap settings activity
and i can't find it in the given android docs
how do i can provide an intent to start the wifi ap settings?

for example i can start my wifi settings like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

and when it comes to wifiap settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code for WiFi Connection in Android.

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
```

Comment: sorry, what I mean is how to start the wifi AP Settings Activiy in my phone

Comment: "wifi ap" means make your phone as a hotspot

Comment: (clarifying) Before ICS you could call the WiFi Settings activity directly with an intent. Now it doesn't seem possible because Google has refactored the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use an intent to start the Wifi AP (i.e. tethering) activity.

I tried to find something I while back and tried a few suggestions I found, but couldn't get anything to work.